# How to launch dropbox

Tags: dropbox

I am new to Ubuntu. Whenever I try to launch Dropbox by clicking the icon in Dash it asks for authentication password. After I put password the dialog box disappears and nothing happens. Want to save the files uploaded from PC.

Comment: Open a terminal, type `dropbox` and paste the output in your question.

Comment: status       get current status of the dropboxd
 help         provide help
 puburl       get public url of a file in your dropbox
 stop         stop dropboxd
 running      return whether dropbox is running
 update       download latest version of dropbox
 start        start dropboxd
 filestatus   get current sync status of one or more files
 ls           list directory contents with current sync status
 autostart    automatically start dropbox at login
 exclude      ignores/excludes a directory from syncing
 lansync      enables or disables LAN sync

Comment: What is your Ubuntu version ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to reinstall Dropbox using the official Dropbox PPA :

```
sudo apt-get purge dropbox
sudo apt-add-repository "deb http://linux.dropbox.com/ubuntu trusty main"
```

*In the previous command replace `trusty` (Ubuntu 14.04) with your current Ubuntu version.*

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver pgp.mit.edu --recv-keys 1C61A2656FB57B7E4DE0F4C1FC918B335044912E
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install dropbox
```

---

Launch Dropbox using your Dash, or in a termianl (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) :

```
dropbox
```

Answer (score 0):

Python3-gpg is required for Dropbox to work .. if its not installed use 
sudo apt install python3-gpg 
Once installed , launch Dropbox , it will take u your browser to login and connect ur account . Once done , Dropbox will be integrated to ur file manager. Hope this helps.. 
I am also new to ubuntu , this worked for me.